# LastContentModifiedDate of A Site Collection

Tags: powershell, site-collection, property

How to determine the `LastContentModifiedDate` of a Site Collection using Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using below script

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$site.LastContentModifiedDate
```